# 2 single slit experiments in parallel

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

I’ve recently being reading a bit on information theory and quantum mechanics was introduced. Of course the 2 slit experiment came up. I wonder about something but have not been able to find any info from Google or here.

So consider the usual 2 slit setup with one difference - an opaque barrier is placed connecting the screen and the midpoint of the barrier between the slits. This to me sounds like a parallel version of the single slit experiment, but with a single shared light source.

What would an observer on each side of the new barrier see? My intuition is that the new barrier is effectively a detector, since one of the observers will observe each photon on their side. Is there any account of such an experiment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The introduction of an opaque barrier between the slits (if I understand the question correctly, I include an image for reference) [image: Double slit experiment with an opaque wall preventing interference of paths] corresponds to discarding the wave-function coming from the other slit. Effectively, whatever result you get at the "output" screen will correspond to the output one would obtain if the other slit was shut.

Now, as you are studying the effects of having 'something' between the slits, you might be interested in reading about the effects of electromagnetism in the double slit experiment (cf. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov–Bohm_effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect), and Sakurai's Modern Q.M. Ch. 2.6 and 2.7). This effect explains the shift on the output screen due to an interaction of the photon field with the electron field through the electromagnetic potential.

I hope this answer brings you new knowledge and interesting questions!

HTH!

Comment: That was exactly what I had in mind.